# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'

Tags: python, installation, pip, openpyxl

I am trying to download openpyxl 2.6.2 specifically because that's the version that [this book](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter13/) uses for its Excel automation examples. My current python version in Ubuntu is 3.8.5, though I have downloaded python 3.9.0 on my desktop, and my current Python Shell is 3.9.0

First I tried just using the code from the book, but got this error:

```
gcab@DESKTOP:~$ pip install --user -U openpyxl==2.6.2
Command 'pip' not found, but there are 18 similar ones.
```

I figured out that I needed to use pip3 not pip to install (maybe this is why it won't import in the python shell?) but I got it to install.

```
gcab@DESKTOP:~$ pip3 install --user -U openpyxl==2.6.2
Collecting openpyxl==2.6.2
  Downloading openpyxl-2.6.2.tar.gz (173 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 173 kB 507 kB/s
Collecting et_xmlfile
  Downloading et_xmlfile-1.0.1.tar.gz (8.4 kB)
Collecting jdcal
  Downloading jdcal-1.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.5 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: openpyxl, et-xmlfile
  Building wheel for openpyxl (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for openpyxl: filename=openpyxl-2.6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl size=245216 sha256=77b53f3225fc950489bccb7f8a0684af70240ca7e9bbf1b2df85f6383a1a596e
  Stored in directory: /home/gcab/.cache/pip/wheels/97/27/98/11bd6a09ec9aa1034ea765af5c2a9d71589c1f012f86fc2481
  Building wheel for et-xmlfile (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for et-xmlfile: filename=et_xmlfile-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl size=8915 sha256=587d3cf5b7362f3930e45c912b901dd236abfdbc379bbdc35880bd8120bfbda5
  Stored in directory: /home/gcab/.cache/pip/wheels/6e/df/38/abda47b884e3e25f9f9b6430e5ce44c47670758a50c0c51759
Successfully built openpyxl et-xmlfile
Installing collected packages: et-xmlfile, jdcal, openpyxl
Successfully installed et-xmlfile-1.0.1 jdcal-1.4.1 openpyxl-2.6.2
```

I went to the Python 3.9.0 Shell to run the import command like the book says, but got this error message.

```
>>> import openpyxl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    import openpyxl
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'
```

I thought maybe it didn't install right? So tried reinstalling openpyxl to see if it hadn't fully downloaded, and I tried pip3 freeze (and the right openpyxl version shows up). Any suggestions?

```
gcab@DESKTOP:~$ pip3 install --user -U openpyxl==2.6.2
Requirement already up-to-date: openpyxl==2.6.2 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (2.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: jdcal in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from openpyxl==2.6.2) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: et-xmlfile in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from openpyxl==2.6.2) (1.0.1)
```

```
gcab@DESKTOP:~$ pip3 freeze
openpyxl==2.6.2
```

Comment: This can happen if you have multiple python installations. Calling `pip`or `pip3` might not install into the python you think it does... Try with `python -m pip install openpyxl` and replace `python` with whatever you use to start your python 3.9.0 shell.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using some notebook (Jupyter) or Python interpreter directly from terminal?

I recommend you use a notebook, like Jupyter. Then, use the following command:

```
# Install a pip package in the current Jupyter kernel
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install numpy
```

I get this awnser from here:
http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/